# Longest username and password accepted for SOCKS5 authentication?

Tags: authentication, proxy, passwords, socks

As seen here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1929 , I would assume that it is either 255, or unlimited in length.

What is the longest possible username and/or password you can use for authenticating a SOCKS 5 proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the same document, and read it as specifically stating that username and password are 1-255 octets long. Assuming single byte encoding this would be 255 chars max.